Cracked staircase baluster
We just noticed that one of our staircase balusters is partially cracked and not aligned like it should be. The orange tape in the picture is just to better indicate the broken baluster.



Here is what the top and bottom look like:


What's the best thing to do here? I have a 3 year old who sometimes grabs onto these as they come down the stairs, and I want it to be safe for him. Watching some youtube videos, I've seen people insert dowel rods in them (but only after they are fully broken). I've seen people fabricate entire new ones (I don't have the skills and time for that). Is it possible to strengthen it without breaking it further? Any resources that might make me a little more comfortable in how these particular ones come in and out, or how I might even try to straighten it?
Edit: Adding picture of nail at the top and the bottom near the Newel post.
Nail at top:

Bottom near Newel post:


it's fully broken it's only holding on by friction.

If you look carefully, the balusters are primarily held in by thin blocks of wood that are cut between the balusters called "filets" they can be nailed in, glued in or both. Usually only nailed in. With a broad edged tool like a putty knfe they can be pulled out without breaking. I did an answer on a more barbaric way to remove them, when the owner was going to finish the stair differently.
How to remove stair spindles from rails
This will get the baluster out. The baluster can be separated the rest of the way by pulling either end directly away from each other, gluing and pressing the 2 ends back together again. This is an oversimplification. This answer was mainly for the removalof the balusters.
You may be able to find a compatible one online sowhere to replace it.

Thank you Jack. I didn't realize that I should pull the filets out to get the baluster out. I had incorrectly assumed that the trim-looking piece (in new picture at the bottom) might need to be pulled back for the baluster to slide out from the side. I do see evidence of a nail in the filet (though sometimes it's hidden well). Also, the top of the baluster seems to be nailed in from the side (see other new picture). I suppose in both these cases I should be able to overcome the nails with putty knives or just a little force? Just don't want to damage anything.

Oh, and in case I ask a finish carpenter to do this for me, how do I pronounce filets?

The bottom most piece, the shoe rail, has a trough in it, which the filet set in. With a  1 1/2" putty  knife on each side, you may be able to pry out the top end of the shoe rail filet. I have heard them pronounced both ways, like the fish fillet, and filet with a hard "T" at the end. While explaining it, I sometimes pronounce it both ways, just to cover my bases. I may even have it spelled wrong. Back at removeing them. With the angle meeting the bottom of the baluster, you should be able to make out which end of the filet shoud come out first, trying the wrong end will jam it in tighter.

Bring the picture to show the carpenter, in this case the proverbial picture is worth...... AND if he doesn't know after that, move on. You want somebody who knows how this goes together.

Yes I see the nail at the top of the baluster. It will be a very small gauge nail that is there to keep the top of the baluster snug to the last filet put in place until the next filet goes in. A light tap behind the baluster to drive it off the brad (nail) will have the baluster out in no time. In one of your new pictures I can see how on one of the filets or maybe it IS fillets.... that one end is higher than the other by a slight amount. I only bring it up for your reference. A fillet like that should be slightly easier to remove, it has more side exposed to apply pressure on for removal.
